# Ignoring a property during deserialization

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I have a class that is serializing very nicely - finally!

Now I want to add a property to this class, that I don't want to be serialized at all.

Is it possible to add this new property with some kind of attribute so that when I call serialize or deserialize methods, this property will go unnoticed?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
[XmlIgnore]
public int DoNotSerialize { get { ... } set { ... } }
```

Answer (score 2):

I think your looking for [`[XmlIgnore]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlattributes.xmlignore.aspx) attribute